# Why is the ConnectionInterface object in my custom consumer web part null?

Tags: web-part, connected-web-parts

I connected two web parts using a Provider web part, an IConnectionInterface and a Consumer web part.

After adding both web parts to my site, the consumer webpart is unable to receive the parameter:

> ConnectionInterface object in Consumer webpart is shown as null.

What could be the reason for this null value?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to provide the relevant connection code for both web parts?

Comment: Also - a well written question encourages people to answer it! Please read [our guidelines](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116) which I've used to improve your post. You can also read [How to Ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for more general guidelines.